# Make Site Responsive

Tags: responsiveness

I have responsive problems with my site.

The theme is Genbu and it has been customized to have two equal sidebars and narrower margins.

This is the custom CSS code:

```css
#main {
padding: 10px;
}
.main-wrap {
float: left;
margin-left: 1rem;
margin-right: 21rem;
}
#sidebar-primary-wrap {
float: left;
margin-left: 1rem;
margin-right: -21rem;
width: 20rem;
}

#sidebar-secondary-wrap {
float: left;
margin-right: -20rem;
position: relative;
width: 20rem;
}
```

I have responsive problems with 240x320, 320x480 and768x1024 device when I checked my site with: http://mattkersley.com/responsive/

Can someone help me with @media stuff?

Comment: From my side, I only see an issue at the 240 iframe. You have horizontal scrolling. You should reduce the font size I think :

   The search bar should also be dropped under the header element, because a part is not visible. So you should apply :

``@media screen and (max-width : 240) {
     body { 
             font-size: 0.8em;
     }

     .search-field {
             margin-top: 50px;
     }
}``

Comment: How do I drop the search bar under header element as suggested? By the way, from what I seen from the responsive testing tool, for 240x320, the width of the main content and the right sidebar  is out.

Comment: I've edited my initial comment. with "margin-top", or if you use absolute position, with the "top" keyword.

Comment: @Alex  I tried using your suggested code, but it doesn't work. The horizontal sliding is still there for 240.

Answer (score 1):

@user29769 To sum it up, if you want to optimize your 240px width site version, you can :
- Align the text from articles (I checked that and either you solved the issue, or it does work from the begenning)
- Reduce the margins between the left and right edges of the screen and the border of the article
- Place the searchbar elsewhere : under the header, or you can also reduce the size of the search bar and keep it on the same line as the search and cancel buttons.

Always be in a mobile user head, what should be convinient ?
also, use your integrated Developper Webtool kit on your web browser (F12), it helps you for many things : 
- you can locally edit in real time CSS to try some stuff on elements
- you can adapt the resolution of the screen directly from the adaptive view
- disable existing css rules, show the calculated one ... it helps in many way

Finally, the media queries are something to use with caution if you want to do a clean work :
chose a few resolution of screens, and make some kind of intervals levels :
[width < 240, 240 < width < 460, 460 < width < 768, etc...]

this way, you can put your media queries, and stick the right adptatives codes into it. (some guys make one css file per resolution, i personnaly make all media queries in one file,  it's a taste matter)

```
/* for all screens with a width lower than 240px */
@media screen and (max-width: 240px) {
   .search-toggle-active.menu-search input {
      margin-left: 30px !important;
   }

   .search-toggle-active.menu-search .search-field {
      width: 12rem;
   }

   .main-wrap {
      padding:0;
   }
}
```

I hope this little help notice can make you undersand some basics about responsiveness. Moreover, I hope it helped you to solve your issue

Comment: I am not very knowledgeable in coding. Could you help me out on this issue. This is my CSS. #main {
padding: 10px;
}
.main-wrap {
float: left;
margin-left: 1rem;
margin-right: 21rem;
}
#sidebar-primary-wrap {
float: left;
margin-left: 1rem;
margin-right: -21rem;
width: 20rem;
}
// remove the max-width: 100%; from that selector
 
#sidebar-secondary-wrap {
float: left;
margin-right: -20rem;
position: relative;
width: 20rem;
}

Comment: You should not use the "//" symbols to make comments in CSS files. You'd rather use this "/* comment */" syntax.

Comment: thank you for the tip. Anyway, by adding the line body{
    overflow-x:hidden; } it seems to hide the horizontal scroll bar. Is this the right or proper way to fix the problem?

Comment: sorry for the late reply. Hiding a horizontal scrollbar by hiding the overflow is not the way to do it. Because your content will be still here, cropped to your page width. You might lose content from the view, and break the design.
One solution could be to reduce the size of the article container, and reduce the font size like I said (not too much, though).

Comment: Thank you for the tip. Anyway, I find the responsive testing tools are not accurate. I tried it with a cell phone (240X320), there is no problem with my site, except the sidebars which are slightly narrower. All the Adsense ads are responsive.